# as.POSIXct, timezone part is ignored

Tags: r, posixct

Here is my example.

```
test <- as.POSIXct(as.Date("2019-11-01"), tz = "UTC")
test
```

It prints:

```
[1] "2019-10-31 19:00:00 CDT"
```

It looks like it ignored `tz` parameter:

```
attr(test, "tzone")
```

returns NULL.

Why is it coming with "19" hours and not 00? How can I make it 00 hours and take `UTC`?

**UPDATE**
Here is even better case:

```
test_2 <- as.POSIXct("2019-11-01 00:00:00", tz = "UTC")
str(test_2)
attr(test_2, "tzone")
strftime(test_2, "%H")
```

It generates:

```
POSIXct[1:1], format: "2019-11-01"
[1] "UTC"
[1] "19"
```

Now it looks like parameter `tz` is not ignored, but hour is 19, but why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `with_tz` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
test1 <- with_tz(as.Date("2019-11-01"), tzone = 'UTC')
attr(test1, 'tzone')
#[1] "UTC"
```

---

Also, `as.POSIXct` can be directly applied

```
test2 <- as.POSIXct("2019-11-01", tz = "UTC")
test2
#[1] "2019-11-01 UTC"
attr(test2, 'tzone')
#[1] "UTC"
```

---

With `strftime`, use the option for `tz`

```
strftime(test2, "%H", tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "00"
```

If we check the `strftime`, it is doing a second conversion with `as.POSIXlt` and then with `format` gets the formatted output

```
strftime
function (x, format = "", tz = "", usetz = FALSE, ...) 
format(as.POSIXlt(x, tz = tz), format = format, usetz = usetz, 
    ...)
```

According to `?as.POSIXlt`

> tz - time zone specification to be used for the conversion, if one is required. System-specific (see time zones), but "" is the current time zone, and "GMT" is UTC (Universal Time, Coordinated). Invalid values are most commonly treated as UTC, on some platforms with a warning.

```
as.POSIXlt(test2)$hour
#[1] 0
as.POSIXlt(test2, tz = "")$hour
#[1] 20
```

The `""` uses the `Sys.timezone` by default

```
as.POSIXlt(test2, tz = Sys.timezone())$hour
#[1] 20
```

Comment: @user1700890 i get `hour(test2)#
[1] 0`

Comment: Thank you, test2 <- as.POSIXct("2019-11-01", tz = "UTC") with strftime(test2, "%H") returns 19 Do you have any guesses why? I also updated my post –

Comment: @user1700890 for me, it is returning 20.  as per the documentation, when we don't provide `tz`, it uses `""` and then it is using the current time zone of your system

Comment: @user1700890 you can check with `as.POSIXlt(test2, tz = Sys.timezone())$hour`

Comment: This works fine. `test2 <- as.POSIXlt("2019-11-01", tz = "UTC")`  `strftime(test2, "%H")`.  Returns `00`. I guess I have to be careful with POSIXct, since it is not part of `strftime`

Comment: @user1700890 I would use the `hour` from lubridate` or you can directly get with `format(test2, "%H")`

Comment: @user1700890 if you `unclass(test2)` will return the components as a `list` from `POSIXlt`